# Solver Foundation Optimization - 1D Bin Packing

Tags: c#, optimization

I want to optimize loading marble blocks into trucks. I do not know, if I can use Solver Foundation class for that purpose. Before, I start writing code, I wanted to ask it here.

- Marble can be in any weight between 1 to 24 Tons.
- A truck can hold maximum of 24 Tons.
- It can be loaded as many marble cubes, as it can take up to 24 tones, which means there is no Volume limitation.
- There can be between 200 up to 500 different marble blocks depending on time.

GOAL - The goal is to load marble blocks in minimum truck shipment.

How can I do that without writing a lot of if conditions and for loops?

Can I use Microsoft Solver Foundation for that purpose?

I read the documentation provided by Microsoft however, I could not find a scenario similar to mine.

`M1+ M2 + M3 + .... Mn <=24`   this is for one truck shipment.

Let say there are 200 different Marble weights and Marble weights are Float.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to get out of doing your homework or...?

Comment: no, there is no such real life task or homework. I am trying to learn for my self knowledge. I believe I can use this knowledge in future. Besides, I am not a student. All I want is to learn coding better!

Comment: Are you familiar with bin packing algorithms?  That's where I would start for approaching this problem.  There's good information on WikiPedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I am now googling and read documents about bin packing algorithms.

Comment: Mellakomb. I have read the article. I wrote my own code with First Fit Algorithm. But as it was stated in the article, it is not efficient. Again, the article says it is more efficient to sorting elements in decreasing order which I also tried in my code. I will go on reading

Comment: This is perfectly legitimate question.

Comment: Hi Ken! thanks for spending time for me and showing this meta post. I am trying to learn everything and also site voting things as well. In the beginning, I might have not shown necessary voting however, now I am voting up and ticking whenever I get a satisfying answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Microsoft Solver Foundation to solve this problem.
An example of such a solution can be found [here](http://www.amsterdamoptimization.com/models/msf/oml.pdf) where the OML for the bin packing problem is as follows:

```
Model[ 
  Parameters[Sets,Items,Bins], 
  Parameters[Integers,OrderWidth[Items],BinWidth[Bins]], 

  Decisions[Integers[0,1],x[Items,Bins]], 
  Decisions[Integers[0,1],y[Bins]], 

  Constraints[    
    Foreach[{i,Items},Sum[{j,Bins}, x[i,j]]==1 ], 
    Foreach[{j,Bins}, Sum[{i,Items}, OrderWidth[i]*x[i,j]] <= BinWidth[j]], 
    Foreach[{i,Items},{j,Bins}, y[j] >= x[i,j]] 
  ], 

  Goals[Minimize[UsedBins->Sum[{j,Bins},y[j]]]] 
]
```

It would be easy to change OrderWidth to MarbleWeight and BinWidth to TruckCapacity (or just 24 in your case)